100% Testing Accuracy on Small Image Testing Set
I'm a little worried because I'm getting 100% accuracy on my test set. The test set is relatively small (16 images) because the dataset overall is very small (40 images), and I assume that contributes. I want to say it's overfitting, but also because it's a test set I'm not sure I can. It just seems very unlikely that it's actually 100% accurate but I'm not sure how else to test it given the dataset that's available to me.
I have confirmed that there are no duplicates in my test set as in my training set, and I don't do any feature engineering because I'm doing image processing. I'm sort of (not quite) doing a type of metric learning, my latent space is just very divisible.
I'm not sure if my results are publishable because I'm so sketched out by the 100% accuracy.
I'm assuming it's got a very low variance? How do I properly evaluate my data?

You could use a cross validation, like KFold to see if changing training set and test set the performances change.
You divide dataset in k subsets (or folds) and in a for loop you use k-1 folds as train set and the other k-th fold as test set; in each cycle these sets changes, since you use a different fold as test set and the remaining as train set.
With 40 records, you could use a KFold with k=8: this way you'll use 5 records as test set and 35 records as train set, at each round (note as the numbers of cycles is equal to k value).
At the end of the loop you take the mean of scores (such as accuracy) computed in each cycle, and this lets you to be more confident about your model.
When you have few records inside dataset you can use Leave one out cross validation, that is a Kfold but with only one record in the test set for each loop cycle (in this case this is a KFold wih k=40).
